# How to import 'window' into middleware on Express?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, cookies, vue-cookies

I have middleware which gets data from cookie (I use `vue-cookies`).

```
  try {
      if (window.$cookies.get('region')) {
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
          `region=${window.$cookies.get('region')};path=/`
        ])
      } else {
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
          `region=${process.env.DEFAULT_REGION};path=/`
        ])
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
```

**Everything works correctly**, but in server terminal I got that:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at server.js:3102:7
    at promisify (server.js:2522:15)
    at middlewareSeries (server.js:2501:10)
    at server.js:2502:12
    at async module.exports../.nuxt/server.js.__webpack_exports__.default (server.js:1964:3)
```

Should I just leave it be, or there is opportunity to fix it?

Comment: hi try to add this.window..

Comment: I tried. `Unresolved variable window`

Comment: have you try it will document.cookies?

Comment: It also works, but still `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: try it like this res.cookie('keyname'); and try to console it and if it is possible try to post server side code snippet as well

Comment: This doesn't work at all `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You clearly try to use it in the code that runs on server side, you can't expect window to exist.

Comment: Yeah, I have already read, that `window` doesn't exist on server side, but still, how can I use cookie there?

Comment: You could start with providing all relevant information, because you're the only person who saw your project. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If you use Nuxt, it's treated in a special way, but the question doesn't even mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to get access to this field I just used `req.cookies.region`

Thanks for help everyone!